Error loading FastText model: "ValueError: has wrong file format!"
I'm trying to load a FastText model using the following code:
`
import fasttext

model = fasttext.load_model('/path/Fastext_model_tweet.bin')

`
However, I'm encountering the following error:
ValueError: /path/Fastext_model_tweet.bin has wrong file format! 
I downloaded the model from this link. The model has been cited in several research papers, but none of them provide details on how to use it or mention any errors they encountered.
I've verified the file path, and the .bin file exists at the specified location. Given that the model has been used in other studies, I assume it should work, but I'm not sure what might be causing this issue.
Has anyone encountered this problem before or has any idea what could be going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I expected the model to load without issues, given that it has been used in multiple research papers. I assumed the .bin file was in the correct format for the FastText library, as other models I’ve worked with loaded without any problems.
